# View a query from the mysql by join

Tags: php, mysql

My schedule has a section for employee leave.

The structure of its table Vacation is as follows

Which is stored in the sender and Substitute section of a user ID

| id | sender | Substitute |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 6 |

I want to connect to the user table and extract users whose numeric ID is in the table

This is the structure of my user table

| id | username | fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | jhon | jhon smith |
| 6 | karen | karen smith |

Now I want to show in the section for the manager the list of all vacations in the vacation table along with the full name of the sender and successor

| vacationId | sender Fullname | Substitute Fullname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | jhon smith | karen smith |

How can I do this?

I am using the following query but I have a problem with how to display it

```
SELECT * 
FROM vacation 
LEFT OUTER JOIN user ON vacation.sender=user.user_id AND vacation.Substitute=user.user_id
```

Comment: You need 2 joins one for sender and one for substitute.

Comment: @P.Salmon Can you give an example?

Comment: @P.Salmon An error will be printed when I do this

Comment: Show your code and the full error message or post to a fiddle.

Comment: @P.SalmonI posted it at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query contains columns which could be present with the same name in more than one table you are referencing, hence the not unique error. It's best if you make the references explicit and/or use table `aliases` when joining. Additionally you mentioned `user_id` that does not exist.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    v.id as vacationID, 
    u1.fullname as sender_Fullname, 
    u2.fullname as substitute_Fullname 
FROM vacation  as v
LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u1 ON v.sender=u1.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN users as u2 ON v.Substitute=u2.id
```

See Demo in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=f2790eadca046f2fddb4d6368ad7a941)*

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked for me, but another problem that exists in the vacation table, I have a series of other information, such as registration time and end time, how to display them.

Comment: @Alfa if the answer solved your problem you should mark as accepted . You can post another question or add all the information of the problem in the question not in the comments section

Comment: Add them in your `SELECT` statement. Like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=3bd1a87c902e9fa2865e161fcb5b72a0